# Different versions of Groovy for Grails and Gradle

Tags: grails, groovy, gradle

By gvm I installed grails and gradle.

```
$ grails --version

 | Grails Version: 3.0.5
 | Groovy Version: 2.4.4
 | JVM Version: 1.7.0_80

$ groovy --version

 Groovy Version: 2.4.4 JVM: 1.7.0_80 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux

$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.6
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-08-10 13:15:06 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     233bbf8e47c82f72cb898b3e0a96b85d0aad166e

Groovy:       2.3.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.7.0_80 (Oracle Corporation 24.80-b11)
OS:           Linux 3.19.0-28-generic amd64
```

How do I make groovy versions match?

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

Grails and gradle come bundled with specific versions of groovy. They don't need to match